# Accessing object's parameters in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Having an object structure like this:

```
anObject = {
    "name_0" : [{info: "xxx", id: 1}],
    "name_1" : [{info: "aaa", id: 4}],
    "name_2" : [{info: "bbb", id: 6}],
    ... 
};
```

so, the key is `name_[i]` and the value is an array containing some data.

I want to print the data like:

```
key
- value
key
- value
- value
```

(there could be more than one array for a key). So I'm using two `ng-repeat`s:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in $ctrl.anObject">{{key}}
    <div ng-repeat="x in value">-  {{x}}
</div>
```

the code above show them right but I want to be able instead of the whole array to show only the id, like:

```
key
- value.id
key
- value.id
- value.id
```

I tried like this but it puts the data the same way as the previous version.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in $ctrl.anObject">{{key}}
    <div ng-repeat="x in value">-  {{x.id}}
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you mean this `name_0
- 1
name_1
- 4
name_2
- 6` ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey exactly

Comment: I managed to put the whole array but I must show only that id

Comment: your code looks OK then

Comment: can you add a running script ?

Comment: I will try but it's difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var app  = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){

$scope.anObject = {
    "name_0" : [{info: "xxx", id: 1}],
    "name_1" : [{info: "aaa", id: 4}],
    "name_2" : [{info: "bbb", id: 6}],
      
};
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in anObject">{{key}}
    <div ng-repeat="x in value">-  {{x.id}}
</div> 

</div>
```

Comment: probably I haven't load the whole project, it was correct.